# Option menu same as like Whatsapp

Tags: android, optionmenu

I want Option menu in Action Bar same as like Whatsapp and many other applications.
Check Image shown as below :
[image]

Please help me to get this.

Answer (score 3):

Android documentation says to you how to do that, [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html).

You need to create a new xml inside `menu` res folder.

An example:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <item android:id="@+id/action_search"
          android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_search"
          android:title="@string/action_search"/>
    <item android:id="@+id/action_compose"
          android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_compose"
          android:title="@string/action_compose" />
</menu>
```

> **android:icon**: Used to specify the icon to use
>   **android:title**: The name of the action (Example, if the button does a Search it could be "Search")
>   **android:id**: The ID of the menu, you will use it to know which menu has been clicked

Then to create it in your Activity override `onCreateOptionsMenu`

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu items for use in the action bar
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.main_activity_actions, menu);
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}
```

Replace `R.menu.main_activity_actions` with your menu name.

To apply the same effect like in yuor screen you should use `android:showAsAction="never"`

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <item android:id="@+id/action_search"
          android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_search"
           android:title="@string/action_search" 
           android:showAsAction="never"
    />
    <item android:id="@+id/action_compose"
          android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_compose"
          android:title="@string/action_compose" 
          android:showAsAction="never" />
     </menu>
```

---

```
android:showAsAction=["ifRoom" | "never" | "withText" | "always" | "collapseActionView"]
```

`android:showAsAction` is used to say how Android should show the icon; if you put `ifRoom` Android will try to add it as icon if there are space; if you use "never" it will add it in the `overflow` menu.

Official doc:

> **ifRoom**    Only place this item in the Action Bar if
>   there is room for it.
>
> **withText**  Also include the title text (defined by
>   android:title) with the action item. You can include this value along
>   with one of the others as a flag set, by separating them with a pipe
>   |.
>
> never Never place this item in the Action Bar.
>
> **always**    Always place
>   this item in the Action Bar. Avoid using this unless it's critical
>   that the item always appear in the action bar. Setting multiple items
>   to always appear as action items can result in them overlapping with
>   other UI in the action bar.
>
> **collapseActionView**    The action view
>   associated with this action item (as declared by android:actionLayout
>   or android:actionViewClass) is collapsible.
>
> Introduced in API Level **14**.

If you use it in API < 14 it will just be ignored.

Comment: Yes, using Support Library.